# Hiding columns in excel based on the value of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to hide the column if all value from row 3 to 10 are zero in that column, so I create formula in the row 11 which is sum of the value from row 3 to 10

Basicly I can create code like this

```
If Range("B11").Value = 0 Then
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Else

Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If

If Range("C11").Value = 0 Then
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Else

Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
```

but how to simply this, because I want to this macro run from Column B to FV,

or maybe any other solution to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well placed loop would help and the join function:

```
Dim X as Long
Columns("B:FV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
For X = 2 To 178
    If Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Range(Cells(3, X).Address & ":" & Cells(10, X).Address).Address).Value), "") = "00000000" Then Columns(X).Hidden = True
Next
```

Unhide ALL the columns first then you have removed the need for your else statement

Edit: With this solution, you also don't need your formula in row 11.

Comment: Thanks Dan, basicly this check if every cell have zero value or not,

Comment: Correct, I chose this over a sum formula as if you have one cell at 1 and one at -1 it will be incorrectly hidden, with my code it will not be hidden :)

Comment: were algebraic sum of values an issue then it'd be faster to use COUNTIF and also shorten the code inside the `For X` loop to `Columns(x).Hidden = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(3, x), Cells(10, x)), 0) = 8`. But this still iterates through ALL column range and hides the trapped ones one by one, which could result in performance issue

Comment: Good call on the countif :)

Answer (score 2):

I have surprised no one write the easiest answer.

```
for i = 2 to 178
    if cells(11, i).value = 0 then
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    end if
next
```

Comment: I pretty much did just that, I just took away the need for an excel formula in the sheet. Also your code doesn't unhide in the scenario where the data now determines that it should. Also Dim your variable as a long ;)

Comment: Of course, all of the answers are correct. I just wrote the one that occur everyone's mind at first.
but why long?

Comment: Use the Long data type to contain integer numbers that are too large to fit in the Integer data type.

Comment: @ShaggyRogers - is 178 too large?

Comment: Nope its not right now. @Dan was telling you for best practice.

Comment: Thanks @DanDonoghue. :)

Comment: Long is used as in the vba environment, integers are converted to longs for processing but still have integer restrictions do a google or stackoverflow search for cba long versus integer

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Ali

Comment: as long as (only) concise code is concerned you may shorten the code inside the `for i ` loop just to `Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = cells(11, i).value = 0`. But I'll point out that both iterating through ALL columns and  hiding them in multiple statements can have significant impact on code speed (if relevant)

Comment: I've been searching for an answer for more than 45 mins and I can't believe that this is what I needed. I could have code it by myself if I would knew the syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Heres one way.

```
Sub test()
Dim iStart  As Long:        iStart = Range("B1").Column
Dim iFin    As Long:          iFin = (Range("FV1").Column) - 1
Dim iCntCol As Long:       iCntCol = iStart 'Col B is #2
    For iCntCol = iStart To iFin 'FV is Col # 178
        If Cells(11, iCntCol).Value = 0 Then
            Columns(iCntCol).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
          Else
            Columns(iCntCol).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
         End If
    Next iCntCol
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shag

Answer (score 1):

should performance be an issue, consider what follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub hide()
Dim found As Range

With Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("B11:FV11"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn)
    .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R3C:R10C)"
    Set found = GetZeroColumns(.Cells, 0)
End With
If Not found Is Nothing Then found.EntireColumn.Hidden = True    

End Sub


Function GetZeroColumns(rng As Range, value As Variant) As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim found As Range

With rng
    Set found = .Find(What:=value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = found.Address
        Set GetZeroColumns = found
        Do
            Set GetZeroColumns = Union(GetZeroColumns, found)
            Set found = .FindNext(found)
        Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer

Answer (score 1):

We could use a more versatile code to do this, by not hard coding the range of consideration, so that it can be reused in many places. Consider below, the `For...Next` loop will test each cell in `Selection`. `Selection` is the current selected cells. So just select the cells you want the code to run on. If a cell's value equals 0, then the column will be marked for hiding. I'd also not recommend hiding the column one-by-one, it makes the code unnecessarily slow, especially when there are a lot of formulas in the sheet or there are many columns to hide. So what i did is just mark the columns for hiding using the `Union` function. Then hide them at one go which you can see at the last line of the code.

```
Sub HideZerosByColumn()
    Dim iRng As Range
    Dim uRng As Range
    Set uRng = Nothing
    For Each iRng In Selection
        If iRng = 0 And Not IsEmpty(iRng) Then
            If uRng Is Nothing Then Set uRng = iRng Else Set uRng = Union(uRng, iRng)
        End If
    Next iRng
    If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Before running the code, select the range for consideration.

[image]

After running the code

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer KS, i still not familiar with this coding. But i will try it , thanks